# Add a li element with a specific class - Wordpress plugin edit

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress with the plugin WP Store Locator, this plugin finds nearby stores between a range and when it dosn't find any store shows "no result".

When it can't find any store I want to add a link saying something like "Can't find your store? Add it here"

With the explorer inspector I found out this:

• This is the view when it finds a store:

[image]

• And this the view when it dosn't:

[image]

How can I add a link to `<li class="wpsl-no-result-msg">`? I'm really new to this so I don't know where to even start looking for what I want to do, any help will be well received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: find out plugin file  which have this html code and add there only.

Comment: Thanks, I'll search for that.

Answer (score 0):

Stores are listed using ajax call in a WP Store locator plugin.
So you can use some jquery to achieve goal.

For example, if there is wpsl-no-results-msg class on ajax complete, then update the html using jquery :

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, response, settings ) {
      /*You can play with this console log data*/
      console.log(settings);
      console.log(response);
      console.log(event);
      
      if(jQuery('li').hasClass('wpsl-no-results-msg')){
            jQuery('li.wpsl-no-results-msg').html("HTML <a href=''>Link</a> ");
      }
    });
```